# How can I change what printStacktrace() does for Exception?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception

I have tried  making a new class that extending Exception and overriding printstacktrace. Problem now is, when it try something like thr following, I get an error "Unreachable catch block for LoggerException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

public class LoggerException extends Throwable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
public void printStackTrace() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.printStackTrace();

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("custom app exception");
    logger.log(Level.WARNING,getMessage(),this);

}

}


try {
  //do something that does throw anything. but just incase there is a null pointer or something

} catch (LoggerException e) { // error: Unreachable catch block for LoggerException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extend RuntimeException class

Comment: Yes. But even if it does it doesn't help you to change IOException printStackTrace method behavior